# Proper way to 301 redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a site of mine that has its own homepage and a blog under domain.com/blog/. What is the proper way of me sending the domain.com/blog/ requests to domain.com/ while sending a 301 to the browser so that search engines know that the URL has moved?

This is what I have, but not working at all.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^domain.com/blog/ [nc]
RewriteRule ^/blog/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

I have replaced the domain.com to my actual domain.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need $1 in RewriteRule since you want to redirect users coming from domain.com/blog to domain.com. Besides, your $1 doesn't substitute anything because you don't use any parentheses in your regex.

**EDIT:**

This should work for you.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com/blog/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/blog/$ http://www.domain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I added the configuration in my above post, please try it out to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape the periods in the first line.

==NEW CODE==

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.domain\.com/blog/ [nc]
RewriteRule ^/blog/$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```